# Solving an exercise in Milnor-stasheff's "characteristic classes"

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology-cohomology

I am trying to solve the following exercise (which is an exercise in Milnor-Stasheff's book). It basically says the following:

> Let $ M =S^n $ be the $n$-sphere and let $TM$  be its tangent bundle, and let $A =\left\lbrace  (v, -v) :  v \in S^n \right\rbrace  \subset S^n\times S^n$ be the anti-diagonal. I need to show that the total space  $TM$ is homeomorphic  to $ S^n\times S^n-A$ , and I need to use  excision and homotopy to show that
>   $H^*(TM, TM_0)\cong H^*(S^n\times S^n, S^n\times S^n-\text{ diagonal})\cong H^*(S^n\times S^n, A)\subset H^*(S^n\times S^n).$

The hint for the first part was to use stereographic projection which basically tells me that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$... How can I continue from here?

I also need some help for the second part please (I didn't quite get where/how to use excision) ?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Note that for $x\in \mathbb S^n$, the tangent space $T_x \mathbb S^n$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb S^n\setminus \{-x\}$ via the stereographic projection (from $-x$).

Comment: are you sure it is not mispelled? In the case $n=1$ we have $TM=S^1\times\mathbb R$ and $TM_0=S^1\times\{0\}$, while $A$ is a cirlcle in a torus. So  the pair $(S^1\times S^1,A)$ is homeomorphic to $(S^1\times S^1,S^1\times\{p\})$. Now $H^*(S^1\times \mathbb R, S^1\times\{0\})$ is different from $H^*(S^1\times S^1,S^1\times\{p\})$. Isn't it?

Comment: $TM_0$ is the zero section or the complement of the zero section?

Comment: @user126154 It's the zero section.

Comment: I'm afraid that with the zero section the example I gave shows that there is a problem. (is the example correct or am I making stupid mistakes?)

Comment: on the other hand, it $TM_0$ is the complement of the zero section (note: the zero section is the diagonal) the excision gives you immediately the first isomorphism.

Comment: aha! I picked the book: page 89, beginning of chapter 8: $E_0$ is the COMPLEMENT of the zero section!

Comment: @user126154 Oups :( You are absolutely right... That was my bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I write an answer summarizing the discussions in the comments.

Point 1) the homeomorphism.

For any $v\in S^n$, let $\pi_v:S^n\setminus\{-v\}\to T_vS^n$ be the stereographic projection with pole $-v$ to the tangent space $T_vS^n$. (Note that in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ the tangent space at $v$ is its orthogonal.)

The map $(v,u)\mapsto (v,\pi_v(u))$ gives the desired homeo.

Point 2) the isomorphisms of homology.

$TM_0$ denotes the complement of the zero section (see the quoted book, beginning of chapter 8).

The zero section corresponds to the diagonal under our homeomorphism.

Thus, excision gives $H^*(S^n\times S^n,S^n\times S^n-diagonal)=H^*(S^n\times S^n -A, S^n\times S^n-diagonal -A)=H^*(TM,TM-zero section)=H^*(TM,TM_0)$.

The last isomorphisms follows from the fact that $S^n\times S^n-diagonal$ retracts to $A$