# Relative cohomology of a vector space module non-zero vectors

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes

I am trying to explicitly compute the relative cohomology groups $H^m(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n_0;\mathbb Z)$, where $\mathbb R^n_0$ is all the non-zero vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. I think that the answer is that $H^0$ and $H^n$ are $\mathbb Z$, and all others vanish, but that is only from trying to understand a proof (from Milnor and Stasheff's "Characteristic classes," where the Euler class is defined).

Any suggestions on how to show this?

Comment: Are you familiar with long exact sequences of a pair? (btw I'm studying the same book :)  )

Comment: Yes, that is actually quite useful. So everything can be computed just using the sequence $H^0(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n_0;\mathbb Z)\to H^0(\mathbb R^n;\mathbb Z)\to H^0(\mathbb R^n_0;\mathbb Z)\to H^1(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n_0;\mathbb Z)\to \cdots$?

Comment: For $i>0$, $H^i(\mathbb{R}^n)=0$, that is, "every third" element is zero. Therefore, $H^i(\mathbb{R}_0^{n})\to H^{i+1}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^{n}_0)$ is an isomorphism. Now $\mathbb{R}^{n}_0$ deformation retracts to the sphere $S^{n-1}$ so you reduced this to the cohomologies of a sphere $S^{n-1}$...

Comment: Of course. Thanks! If you want to make that an answer I'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: That's ok for the moment. Of course, still some works remains to be done to compute the cohomologies of spheres, but that's probably well known. Good luck with Milnor/Stasheff studies! ;)

Comment: see also that http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721919/solving-an-exercise-in-milnor-stasheffs-characteristic-classes/722013#722013

Comment: The trick to computing the groups $H^m(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n_0;\mathbb Z)$ and the groups $H^m(S^n;\mathbb Z)$ is not to try to first compute one and then derive the other, but instead to compute them both by a kind of double induction argument. You'll find this argument in any algebraic topology text such as Hatcher's.